# Code to improve with neon

Tags: c, ios, assembly, arm, neon

I tried to improve some code, but I wasn´t able, so I ask for help here, I also tried with intrinsics, but if you want to use intrinsic you need to use the GCC compiler, this compiler compile slower code than the LLVM, then all the code get slower, so  the best option is to use directly asm.
I put the both functions I want to improve, also the code in neon, the code is returning nonsense numbers.
I really need help with this, any point to the right direction could help me a lot.

The code I want to improve:

```
inline unsigned des(const unsigned char* v0)
{
unsigned r;
r = v0[0]*v0[0];
r += v0[1]*v0[1];
r += v0[2]*v0[2]; 
r += v0[3]*v0[3];
r += v0[4]*v0[4];
r += v0[5]*v0[5]; 
r += v0[6]*v0[6];
r += v0[7]*v0[7];
return r;
}


inline unsigned  suma(const unsigned char* v0)
{
unsigned r;
r = v0[0];
r += v0[1];
r += v0[2]; 
r += v0[3];
r += v0[4];
r += v0[5]; 
r += v0[6];
r += v0[7];
return r;
}
```

Neon code not working

```
unsigned desneon(unsigned v0[8])
{
asm volatile (
              "vld1.32      {d2- d5}, [%0]          \n\t"   
              "vld1.32      {d6- d9}, [%0]          \n\t"   
              "vmul.s32         d0, d2, d6              \n\t"   //d0= d2*d6
              "vmla.s32         d0, d3, d7              \n\t"   //d0 = d0 + d3*d7 
               "vmla.s32        d0, d4, d8              \n\t"   //d0 = d0 + d4*d8 
                "vmla.s32       d0, d5, d9              \n\t"   //d0 = d0 + d5*d9 
             "vpadd.s32         d0, d0                  \n\t"   //d0 = d[0] + d[1]


              :: "r"(v0) : 
              );    
}
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You're not actually returning anything from that method. `d0` ends up with the result you want I'm pretty sure but you actually need to return it.

Comment: Why don't you use vDSP functions in Accelerate.framework ?

Comment: the vDSP is using floats, I suppose this will make the application slower, isn´t it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually return the value. I think you want something like this:

```
unsigned desneon(unsigned v0[8])
{
    unsigned outlo;
    __asm__ volatile (
                      "vld1.32      {d2- d5}, [%1]          \n\t"   
                      "vld1.32      {d6- d9}, [%1]          \n\t"   
                      "vmul.s32     d0, d2, d6              \n\t"   //d0= d2*d6
                      "vmla.s32     d0, d3, d7              \n\t"   //d0 = d0 + d3*d7 
                      "vmla.s32     d0, d4, d8              \n\t"   //d0 = d0 + d4*d8 
                      "vmla.s32     d0, d5, d9              \n\t"   //d0 = d0 + d5*d9
                      "vpadd.s32    d0, d0                  \n\t"   //d0 = d[0] + d[1]
                      "vmov         %0, r4, d0              \n\t"
                      :"=r"(outlo)
                      :"r"(v0)
                      :"d0", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7", "d8", "d9", "r4"
                      );
    return outlo;
}
```

I checked and it seemed to give me the right result. As @Nyx0uf says though, you might want to take a look at the Accelerate framework - it's got a lot of useful stuff in there for doing this with standard method calls rather than hand writing NEON.

Comment: thanks it´s working !!! there is a problem with the accelerate framework, from my point of view it looks like this framework is always using floats, and working with floats will make the app slower.

Comment: Is a bit slow even with some improvements, I put the code of the improvements above, but thank you very much I have a working example to be able to evolve it :D.

Answer (score 0):

- why signed operations when the data is unsigned?
- why read the same data twice?
- your C code's input data is 8bit, but the neon code's is 32bit.

Assuming 32bit input data, I suggest :

```
unsigned desneon(unsigned v0[8])
{
asm volatile (
             "vldmia      {q0-q1}, [%0]          \n\t"   
             "vmul.u32    q0, q0, q0             \n\t"
             "vmla.u32    q0, q1, q1             \n\t"
             "vpaddl.u32  q0, q0                 \n\t"    
             "vadd.u64    d0, d0, d1             \n\t"    
             "vmov        r0, s0                 \n\t"    

              :: "r"(v0) : 
              );    
}
```

While looking impressively short and appearing to be optimized, this neon version won't be much faster (or even slower) because of :

- pipeline interlocks pretty much every step
- a huge hiccup before "vmov r0,s0" (11 cycles)

I advise you to stick to the orignal C code in this case.

Comment: Hi Jake, thanks for the answer, I needed to change this line " "vldmia     %0  ,  {q0-q1}         \n\t"   ", also when I run it, looks like is doing something malign, the app simply stops and do nothing, no erros, no kill, no mem ... nothing, maybe its something related with program counter, but I don´t find the problem.

Comment: maybe due to the last line vmov. I'm not very familiar with inline assembly. Just change it so that the value of s0 is returned.